# Raspivid fails to stream to YouTube - 113 No route to host

Tags: raspivid

I am trying to setup a YouTube livestream. I am using the official Pi cam.

I am using this command:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -vf -hf -fps 30 -b 6000000 | avconv -re -ar 44100 -ac 2 -acodec pcm_s16le -f s16le -ac 2 -i /dev/zero -f h264 -i - -vcodec copy -acodec aac -ab 128k -g 50 -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxx
```

And I am getting this error message:

```
RTMP_Connect0, failed to connect socket. 113 (No route to host) 
rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxx: Unknown error occurred
```

Attached the complete output.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

use

rtmp://x.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/ < SESSION >